# How do I configure this PostgreSQL check for DataDog?

Tags: python, postgresql, datadog

I try to setup a postgres check using DD Agent and i'm getting an error thrown by postgres.py script. As you can see in the screenshot, i'm using this simple query to  get the number of active connections to a db. I've put it inside the /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/postgres.d/conf.yaml like this :

```
- metric_prefix: postgresql
     query: SELECT datname as db_name, count(pid) as active_connections FROM pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' group by db_name;
     columns:
       - name: active_connections
         type: gauge
       - name: db_name
         type: tag
```

The error i get when i run a config check is the following :

```
[root@my_box postgres.d]# datadog-agent check postgres | grep -i -A 20 -B 20  active_connections
Error: postgres:953578488181a512 | (postgres.py:398) | non-numeric value `cldtx` for metric column `active_connections` of metric_prefix `postgresql`
```

If i understood correctly the conf.yaml file is used to call the postgres.py script with certain parameters. The postgres.py script can be found here :
https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/postgres/datadog_checks/postgres/postgres.py

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this looks super weird. you should probably just reach out to support@datadoghq.com to get their input. (You might also consider running your yaml through a yaml linter first just to make sure no formatting stuff is tripping up the agent's interpretations of your configs, but I don't really think that'll cause this. Still, it's a quick thing to check.)

Comment: Thanks @baldr, I verified the yaml file with this online validator : http://www.yamllint.com/ and it seems to be ok. I also raised a ticket to Datadog and i'm waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these kinds of checks, the response order matters, since the columns returned from the DB are going to be mapped back to the names specified in the YAML.

Reading the error message:

> Error: postgres:953578488181a512 | (postgres.py:398) | non-numeric value `cldtx` for metric column `active_connections` of metric_prefix `postgresql`

We can see that the value of `cldtx` is being returned for the `active_connections` column, which in the YAML is declared as a gauge, and this is a string.

The fix should be straightforward, by reordering the YAML, like so:

```yaml
...
     columns:
       - name: db_name
         type: tag
       - name: active_connections
         type: gauge
```

Alternately, if you want to keep the YAML ordered, change the query to:

```yaml
...
     query: SELECT count(pid) as active_connections, datname as db_name FROM pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' group by db_name;
...
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that was indeed the problem.